# Unable to see navigation arrows using Slick Carousel?

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I have a CSS conflict problem when incorporating [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in my personal webpage. Below is a link to the page where you can see that there are no visible navigation arrows.

http://matutor2012.scuola.zanichelli.it/animazionibienniowc/drag_and_drop_insiemi/DDM-004-BN/index.php

Can this be due to CSS in my page colliding with Slick's CSS?

Here how it looks before incorporating the carousel on my page:

http://matutor2012.scuola.zanichelli.it/animazionibienniowc/drag_and_drop_insiemi/DDM-003-BN/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove height form the `.esempio` class and add color in `.slick-prev::before, .slick-next::before` and it's work perfectly

```
.slick-prev::before, .slick-next::before {
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrows are white. Change:

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before
{
color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the color style from slick.css under (slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before) css styles

That is setting the arrows to white which is why they can not bee seen on the page.

Or set these as new styles in your style sheet with the !important tag that way these should be the ones which are used.

Comment: It's better to provide some code that you can *add* to the stylesheet. Removing color styles is not feasible when you're including the stylesheet from a CDN.